TradingView Pine Script Breakout Strategy - Problem same bar close
I build a breakout strategy in Pine Script:

If the close of the current bar is higher than the highest high of the last 100 bars, go long
If the close of the current bar is lower than the lowest low of the last 50 bars, go short
I added a take profit of 25 ticks
No two trades in a row in the same direction

So if it hits the take profit of a long position it closes and waits for a short signal. If it doesn't hit the take profit the trade is reversed in the event of a short signal. Vice versa for a short trade. It works well, except when the strategy is entered and closed at the same bar due to a take profit. It then opens a new trade in the same direction if the long/short condition is valid (see screenshot below).
I cannot figure out how to avoid this. I've tried several combinations with strategy.opentrades.*, *profit, bar_index variables etc. trying to check if the last bar was a take profit or how many bars are between the last take profit and the new entry, but I cannot figure out the right combination. Or maybe there's an easier way.
Edit: If it helps, it's a futures trading strategy. So if you want to check yourself you could use ES1! or NQ1! on a 30 minutes chart for example.
Here's the code:
//@version=5

strategy(title="Breakout", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = false)
periodhh = input(100)
periodll = input(50)
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
hh = ta.highest(periodhh)
ll = ta.lowest(periodll)

pos=0
pos :=  close > hh[1] ? 1 : close < ll[1] ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)

if (pos==1 and pos[2]!=1)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", profit=25)
    
if (pos==-1 and pos[2]!=-1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)   
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", profit=25)



In my example above, 25 ticks is very little for BTC
for debug profit, try this:
if strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0
    profitLevel := open + syminfo.mintick * 25
if strategy.position_size < 0 and strategy.position_size[1] >= 0
    profitLevel := open - syminfo.mintick * 25

plot (
   profitLevel,
  'profitLevel',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.red, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)


full code:
//@version=5

strategy(title="Breakout", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = false)
periodhh = input(100)
periodll = input(50)
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
hh = ta.highest(periodhh)
ll = ta.lowest(periodll)

pos=0
pos :=  close > hh[1] ? 1 : close < ll[1] ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)

var float profitLvl = na

if (pos==1 and pos[1]!=1)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (pos==-1 and pos[1]!=-1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)   

strategy.exit("Take Profit", profit=25)

plot (
   hh,
  'hh',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.gray, 0),
  style          = plot.style_line)
plot (
   ll,
  'll',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.silver, 0),
  style          = plot.style_line)
plot(
   pos,
  "pos",
  editable = false, display = display.data_window)

if strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0
    profitLvl := open + syminfo.mintick * 25
if strategy.position_size < 0 and strategy.position_size[1] >= 0
    profitLvl := open - syminfo.mintick * 25

plot (
   profitLvl,
  'profitLvl',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.red, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)


Sorry, but I don't know how to implement your code into mine. I'm quite a newbie. Your "profitLevel" isn't declared, but you assign it to "open + syminfo.mintick * 25". In my code there is no take profit declared/initialized, because it's in strategy.exit. So I don't know what to do with profitLevel before your code. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

I edited my answer, with the full code

Thank you so much! Works perfectly. You're so much better than ChatGPT. :D I tried so many different versions with ChatGPT, but the output was always buggy, although there are so few lines of codes and a "simple problem" in my newbie opinion. ChatGPT added twice the amount of lines and still didn't work. Thanks a lot!

the number of bars back to pos, should be 1
if (pos==1 and pos[1]!=1)

Try:
//@version=5

strategy(title="Breakout", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = false)
periodhh = input(100)
periodll = input(50)
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
hh = ta.highest(periodhh)
ll = ta.lowest(periodll)

pos=0
pos :=  close > hh[1] ? 1 : close < ll[1] ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)

if (pos==1 and pos[1]!=1)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", profit=25)
    
if (pos==-1 and pos[1]!=-1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)   
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", profit=25)

plot (
   hh,
  'hh',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.gray, 0),
  style          = plot.style_line)
plot (
   ll,
  'll',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.silver, 0),
  style          = plot.style_line)
plot(
   pos,
  "pos",
  editable = false, display = display.data_window)



This was my first version, but when I change it to 1 to check the last bar, all take profits disappear. Look at your chart. All your entries are also your take profit at the same bar for the same price. That's not correct.
